# Ruby ri for page?

Tags: ruby, ri

On my machine, Ruby's `ri` data is in `/usr/share/ri/3.0.0/system`.

Therein is:

- A directory for each found class/module (e.g., `Array`).
- A file `page-*.ri` for each found page (e.g., `page-dig_methods_rdoc.ri`).

I can get the info for a class or method with a command such as `ri Array` or `ri Array#clear`.

How can I get the info from file `page-dig_methods_rdoc.ri`?

Answer (score 0):

Duh.  A friend tells me:  `ri ruby:dig_methods`.